# Inserting images in Word doesn't work

Tags: playonlinux, microsoft-office

I couldn't insert any image with Jpg in Word after installing it. I'm using ubuntu 22.04 and Installed Office using playonlinux
How can I fix it please ?

[image]

[image]

This is the option of paste
[image]

Comment: [does this help](https://www.wikihow.com/Add-an-Image-in-Word)? Without knowing what steps you are taking, it is difficult to understand your question.

Comment: I tried to copy it and past but it past the path of the image .. and tried to drag and drop the image but got windows I posted i the post

Comment: if essential you use MS Word, have you tried using LO Writer, import the jpeg there and then export the document to MS Word as a work around?